# Can we speed up or prevent the need for AuthorizeRequest for image requests using imageresizer?

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, imageresizer

I've just set-up newrelic on an azure cloud service and now sifting through the logs to make any improvements.

For the imageresizer requests, I'm noticing a significant amount of time in AuthorizeRequest, here's a typical transaction:

1. DotNet  AuthorizeRequest    57.6 (%)
2. External    Stream[x.blob.core.windows.net] 24.6
3. DotNet  AcquireRequestState 14.0
4. DotNet  MapRequestHandler   2.7
5. DotNet  ResolveRequestCache 0.5
6. DotNet  Integrated Pipeline 0.3
7. DotNet  UpdateRequestCache  0.2
8. DotNet  SendResponse    0.1

Is AuthorizeRequest actually where the grunt of the image processing occurs? Hence the high percent of batch? Or can I reduce the time spent here re-configuring the app as there needn't be any authorization required for the images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, everything happens during AuthorizeRequest, as this permits the request to be rewritten to a static file (if cached) prior to ProcessRequest.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.